# A SQL query to return customer with the most orders

Tags: sql

Appreciate if you can help me with my school exam question:

For a table of `AllOrder` as described below, what is the SQL query returns the single `customer_id` with the most number of orders?

Assume exactly one customer has placed the most orders.

Below is my column name with its type

- order_num int
- customer_num int
- order_comments varchar

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by first summing per `customer_num` (assuming this is the customer ID), ordering by number of orders and then taking the first row. For example:

```sql
SELECT customer_num,
       COUNT(DISTINCT order_num)
FROM AllOrder
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

As you noted, this would work assuming exactly *one* customer has more orders than anyone else (more distinct `order_num`s).

Answer (score 0):

In standard SQL, you would write:

```
SELECT customer_num, COUNT(*)
FROM AllOrder
GROUP BY customer_num
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

This aggregates the data by customer, counting the number of orders.  It then orders them by the number descending and chooses the first row -- the customer with the most orders.

Not all databases support the `FETCH FIRST` clause, so you might need to use `LIMIT`, `SELECT TOP` or whatever your database suggests for that operation.